# Listview to show exactly two cells of list

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, listactivity, listadapter

i want to create a list view inflating custom cell. The cell size may vary depending on the size of text in it. There can be n number of cells. At a time, i just want to show exactly two cells in the list view. Even when i scroll, the list view should hold exactly two cells, even if the size of cell varies. Can any one suggest a way to implement this?